# Read only n first lines from something

Tags: command-line, console, pipe

When I'm saying something like

```
curl http://example.com/123
```

and I want to read only n first lines, how do I do that? I know that's something like:

```
curl http://example.com/123 | ???
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `head -n D` where `D` can be any integer number. Example:

```
curl http://example.com/123 | head -n 3
```

Comment: how do read the last n lines?

Comment: Easy: **tail -n**

Comment: It seems **head -3** and **head -n 3** and **head --lines=3** are all the same.

Answer (score 2):

For `curl` in particular, there is an option to only load a range of bytes.  Because it's bytes instead of lines, you may need to overestimate and then trim with head or tail, but this might save load-time on long webpages (or the byte-range may be sufficient for your application.)  For example,

```
curl --range 0-99 http://example.com/123
```

will get the first 100 bytes.  (You can also pull out a range in the middle of the page, give multiple disjoint ranges, or use a range measured from the end of the page.)

(I don't know for sure, but I think curl will load the whole webpage even if it's piped to a command that only reads the first few lines.)